# "bluetooth le advertising not supported"?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My Galaxy Note 3 has Android 5.0 (API=21) which provide BLE Peripheral API but when trying to create BLE Peripheral service i'm getting error in log:

```
E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ bluetooth le advertising not supported
```

Does it mean BLE Peripheral will not work on my device? Is it hardware or software limitation?

Comment: There is a reported  [issue here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1570)

Comment: it's about Nexus devices, no such log entry in that issue

Comment: Upss srry [this was the link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/ble-peripheral-mode/201/280106?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000007) for `Note 3`

Comment: Also the Bluetooth chips (not only the OS) has to be capable of peripheral mode. Did you checked yours?

Comment: you can do it with `mBluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();
mBluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedFilteringSupported();
mBluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported();`